# extern C unresolved symbol with gcc 4.8?

Tags: c++, gcc, extern, gcc4.8

I have the following piece of code, that works with gcc 4.3 compiler, but when I compiled with gcc 4.8, got resolved symbol error ( linking time)

```
//test.cc
ULONG CPULimit = 200;
```

// test.h

```
namespace ABC
{
    class STAT
    {
    public:
        static ULONG getCPULimit();
    }
}
```

in the same test.h file itself, I have defined the getCPULimit() function inline

```
inline ULONG
ABC::STAT::getCPULimit()
{
    extern ULONG CPULimit; 
    return CPULimit;
}
```

The above code worked with 4.3 compiler, with 4.8 got unresolved symbol error.

moving extern ULONG CPULimit outside the function, will work but it exposes the global variable. 
now I wrapped the function with extern "C" like this

```
extern "C"
{
    inline ULONG
    ABC::STAT::getCPULimit()
    {
       extern ULONG CPULimit; 
       return CPULimit;
    }
}
```

and surprisingly it worked, 
1) I'm not sure how it worked , could anyone shed some light?  Is this the right way of doing it?

2) what does it mean to have two externs  (one extern C and one extern)

Comment: This is not your actual code, `ULONG` is not a type

Comment: `ULONG` is a `typedef unsigned long` in Windows headers. I suspect, you've updated your `MinGW` from `gcc 4.3` to `gcc 4.8` and got this error?

Comment: Why are you extern "C"'ing a static member of a class?  Isn't that exactly the opposite of what extern "C" is meant to mean (i.e. making sure that a C++ compiler understands it needs to apply a C ABI to a function call to a external C object).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most natural way - make your global variable `static` and make `getCPULimit` function non-inlined and implemented in .cc file.

I'm almost sure having C-ABI-incompatible function within `extern "C"` block is either undefined or forbidden. However, your function is `static`, so it *may* be compatible with C ABI (although it looks like a bad idea). Perhaps someone could bring a quotation from C++ standard about that.

Answer (score 0):

ULONG is not a type, but if you didn't want to use a normal one you could `typedef` one.
EDIT:
ULONG should be ulong.